# Extracting Text In Between Special Characters

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to regex and can't for the life of me figure out how to define this scenario. I have a column in df containing strings, some have a certain ending to them and I need to extract that ending. Sample df:

Sample df

```
   col1
0  Each Wednesday
1  Each 3rd Thursday [EXP 12/31/2019]
2  Each 1st, 4th Friday
3  Each Tuesday [EXP 6/30/219]
4  Each Monday [EXP 3/31/2019]
5  Each 4th Wednesday
```

Desired df output:

```
   col1                                         col2
0  Each Wednesday                                 -
1  Each 3rd Thursday [EXP 12/31/2019]      EXP 12/31/2019
2  Each 1st, 4th Friday                           -
3  Each Tuesday [EXP 6/30/219]             EXP 6/30/219
4  Each Monday [EXP 3/31/2019]             EXP 3/31/2019
5  Each 4th Wednesday                             -
```

I'd like to extract all portions of the strings that is in between the [] and place into a new column. There are a lot of great regex examples on stack, but I need some help with my particular use case as I am currently stuck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) here to get everything between the square brackets. Finally we use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace the `NaN` with a dash `-`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract('\[(.*)\]').fillna('-')
```

---

```
                                 col1            col2
0                      Each Wednesday               -
1  Each 3rd Thursday [EXP 12/31/2019]  EXP 12/31/2019
2                Each 1st, 4th Friday               -
3         Each Tuesday [EXP 6/30/219]    EXP 6/30/219
4         Each Monday [EXP 3/31/2019]   EXP 3/31/2019
5                  Each 4th Wednesday               -
```